# How can I compress a file with Vim?

Tags: vim, compression, gzip

I know that Vim supports editing of compressed files (gzip, bzip2, etc.). But how can I compress and write a text file which is loaded in Vim? I'm sure there's some way to do it, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `autocommands`.

I'd recommend reading `:h gzip-example`.